# THREE.ShaderMaterial is seen inverted by the shadow Camera

Tags: three.js

I have a mesh that i am loading from 3d studio max into three.js. I modified three.js to hold another typed array for the binormal data. It all seems to be working fine and dandy until shadows are involved. For some reason, the shadow map is wrong, and it seems as if its rendering the mesh with faces flipped.

In this example, the shadows are showing up correctly on the floor, because the renderer has

```
.shadowMapCullFace = THREE.CullFaceBack
```

http://dusanbosnjak.com/test/webGL/new/StojadinCeo/stojadinCeo.html

I can get other shadows to show up on my shader, but self shadowing leads to horrible artifacts, and the shadow that my mesh casts on other meshes is always inverted.

I've tried reversing the order in which the face indecis come in, (acb instead of abc), which flips the faces. This creates proper shadow cast, but the mesh shows flipped.

What im thinking of doing at the moment is exporting a flipped mesh, and reversing the cull order in the shaderMaterial, but it would be wonderful to find out why this is happening.

I basically connected the phong and shadow mapping shader chunks with what i've had.

*edit*

Here is an updated scene with some shadow casters and receive shadows on imported meshes

http://dusanbosnjak.com/test/webGL/new/StojadinCeo/stojadinCeo2.html

```
light = new THREE.SpotLight(0xaaaaaa);
light.position.set(10,10,10);

light.shadowCameraVisible = true;
light.shadowDarkness = .5;
light.castShadow = true; 
light.shadowCameraNear = 1;
light.shadowCameraFar = 250;
light.shadowCameraFov = 57;  
light.shadowMapWidth = 2048;
light.shadowMapHeight = 2048;  
scene.add(light);
```

the rest of the meshes just have receiveShadow and castShadow set to true

The shadow shows on the shaderMaterial (i copied the shadowfrag chunk)
THREE.Mesh() with THREE.CubeGeometry() both casts shadows and receives shadows properly, but the shadow cast by the shaderMaterial mesh is inverted.

I can't really isolate this to 50 lines of code as it's a whole import/export process from max.

I don't understand why would the shadow camera render this one particular mesh inverted, while the normal camera renders it correctly, if that is what is happening?

You can zoom out and move the car using wasd

Comment: (1) What is your question? (2) Can you provide a simple, 50-line program that demonstrates the problem? (3) Can you demonstrate the problem on a simple, one-component model?

Comment: (1)What could i have done to cause this one mesh to show inverted in the shadow projection?(2) I updated the example to demonstrate the problem (culling is at default) but i cannot demonstrate it on a a simpler case since it's a part of the importer/exporter i was working on. Is there somewhere you can point me based on the updated example, and maybe i could isolate the code down to something meaningful?

Comment: Sorry, I have tried and tried, but I have no idea what your question is about, nor what the problem is, nor what you mean by "inverted in the shadow projection."

Comment: If you take a look at the wheels (you can drive the car around) you will see that that the shadow is not being cast correctly. It is as if shadow camera sees flipped faces. The roof is not casting a shadow on the floor, and the wheels are casting inside out.

Comment: OK. Now I understand your issue... Unless you changed the default settings, only back-faces cast shadows. Every mesh needs to have thickness. Avoid planes, like the car roof. A work-around: `renderer.shadowMapCullFace = THREE.CullFaceBack;` or `THREE.CullFaceNone`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm still not sure if we're on the same page though :) What I was trying to say is, if you look at the boxes in the second scene, I am still under the impression that their front faces are rendered by all cameras, while my imported mesh renders front face in the main camera, back face to the shadow camera. I'm going to make a new test just to make sure. But if you look at the wheel closer to the camera, it's shadow is hollow (the light doesn't see the hubcap, the backside of the tire is whats casting the shadow).In comparison The top face of the box is not inverted.

Comment: I am further confused by the thickness you mention, the car will theoretically have a volume(either by matting the windows or modeling the interior) but no matter what none of the meshes are likely to be fully closed and have a true volume (even the car body is broken up at every UV seam). If i add the interior ceiling to this model, then yes, i will get a shadow from the 'roof' but it wont be proper, the roof wont be casting it, the backside of the interior ceiling will.

Comment: As I said, only back-faces cast shadows under the default settings. If you want the roof to cast a shadow, you need to follow my advice above and change the settings, or add an interior liner to the roof.

Comment: Hi West, Thanks for your patience. I've setup another test scene and i've concluded that i need to re-read a chapter on openGL shadow mapping

[link](http://dusanbosnjak.com/test/webGL/new/StojadinCeo/stojadinCeo3.html)

Can you take a look at this? I feel like im missing the shadows cast by the planes in one of these combinations.

Comment: Do some studying, and if you still feel like what I am saying is not correct, then please repost with a simple one page demo that illustrates your point.

Comment: Hi West, this seems like a similar issue [link](http://forums.udacity.com/questions/100092865/strange-shadow-mapping-shadows-edit-now-with-screenshots), i abandoned my mesh and setup a scene with just three.js meshes [link](http://dusanbosnjak.com/test/webGL/new/StojadinCeo/stojadinCeo4.html) but i can't say that i understand the results, this seems wrong to me. The cylinder going darker in this case, is it supposed to be happening?

Comment: If you have more issues, please make a new post -- but study webgl shadow mapping first, and see if you can answer the question yourself.

Comment: I understand that this is done because of shadow acne correct? It's a built in feature with a whole approach on building models, but even with that, i'm confused by some of these results. Will re-read, and repost, no point in torturing this thread :)

Comment: I posted an answer you can accept based on your original question. It might be helpful to others to include a screen shot in your post -- if you want. Good luck!

Comment: Hi West, I ended up 'implementing' (not sure if it applies to the dirty hack that i did) variance shadow maps  [link](http://dusanbosnjak.com/test/webGL/new/stojc2/stojadinCeo.html). I ended up using a float buffer. For what i'm doing at the moment, i like the fact that i can blur them more than what three has (i hope i didnt miss something). I can't quite wrap my head around on how i would end up modeling for the flipped shadow approach (if that's what it is, to avoid acne and bias?). I accepted the answer, i'll figure out a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you changed the default settings in three.js, only back-faces cast shadows. A work-around is to set:

```
renderer.shadowMapCullFace = THREE.CullFaceBack;
```

or

```
renderer.shadowMapCullFace = THREE.CullFaceNone;
```

But these options can lead to other issues.

The best approach is to make sure every mesh has depth. Avoid planes, like the car roof. 
For example, you can add an interior liner to the car roof to give it depth.

Shadow mapping in WebGL can be tricky, so read all you can about it so you will be familiar with the issues involved.

three.js r.66

Comment: As of r85, it seems the preferred syntax is `renderer.shadowMap.renderReverseSided = false;`